# Is there a way to learn interacting with the mempool without having to run a full node?

Tags: nodes, pending-transactions, txpool

this link mentions grabbing a free endpoint from quicknode:

https://www.quicknode.com/guides/web3-sdks/estimating-gas-price-using-pending-transactions-in-python

I followed the link and made an account but am only seeing paid options (and doesnt seem infura provides mempool inspection either). Is the only option today to run your own full node with all the disk space it consumes even if it's just to learn how to simulate mempool transactions or are there other options?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into [Blocknative's Mempool Explorer](https://explorer.blocknative.com). You don't need to be on a paid plan to interact with the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can call geth txpool.content() to check the snapshot of Txpool if you don’t have real-time requirement.